# Is this trebuchet based on a real historical model?

Tags: military, weapons, siege

I was watching a clip from Game of Thrones where trebuchets were being launched from ships.  From my research, the closest thing I could find is a [floating arm trebuchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_arm_trebuchet), but rather than dropping straight down, there seems to be a portion with brackets which run down a curved track causing the beam of the trebuchet to rise.

I was not able to find this curved model anywhere.  Has anyone heard of it before, or do you think it was invented for this fictional instance?  I could see it being a space-saving design for use on a ship, but not much more than a regular floating arm...

The model in question is fired at the 3 minute mark [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWChU36nRDI):

Comment: Looked it over a few times, and I believe that depicts a simple catapult firing from a ship, and a trebuchet firing from nearby land (not a ship). The viewpoint ship was either near the harbor docks, or the shore.

Comment: I want to applaud you for including a link to the source of the question in the question. New users don't typically bother to do that without a lot of begging on our part, and you can see how much trouble you doing so saved everyone.

Comment: My first thought was that this might be based on a design sketch in one of Leonardo da Vinci's notebooks, but all I could find were these designs for a [fairly conventional trebuchet](http://www.redstoneprojects.com/trebuchetstore/davincidefensivetrebuchet.html) and a [catapult](https://www.davincilife.com/catapult.html), [catapult](https://leonardodavinci.stanford.edu/projects/catapult/leo14.html) (my apologies for linking second-hand sources, I could not remember where to find high-quality scans of his notebooks). My best *guess* is that this is a modern re-imagining of the trebuchet concept

Comment: Look carefully at the launch angle of the trebuchet. It's been reconfigured not to save space, but to fire more like a mortar than a howitzer. The launch angle is about 55 to 60 degrees, in search of greater height in exchange for reduced distance. It's designed as anti-dragon rather than anti-castle weapon. Ostensibly a regular trebuchet would fire at 45 degree for maximum distance; but in practice, due to air resistance, maximum distance is more likely around 35-40 degrees.; so 55 plus degrees is a lot higher than provides maximum distance.

Answer (score 1):

No. Game of Thrones is a fantasy series, loosely based on medieval and renaissance history. This is an example of fantasy. I've searched for unusual trebuchet types, and came up blank. All I found were common trebuchets.

There's a good reason for that: technology wasn't advanced enough for this kind of trebuchet. It needs guiding rails and pretty smooth ball bearings to overcome friction. Modern [ball-bearings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_bearing) were invented in 1794. They wouldn't be good enough to work on a machine like that. You'd need much better bearings. No idea how accurate, but you'd be thinking at least a century later.

A trebuchet works like a giant sling. The longer the arm, and/or the heavier the counterweight, the further it would reach. It's fairly easy to construct, at least in theory.

The trebuchet you're interested in wouldn't be half as efficient as the common one. A shorter arm, shorter travel time and very complex construction. Likely it might fall apart when it reaches its apogee. The forces it has to withstand are huge. The technology and available materials that can tolerate that kind of stress hadn't been invented yet. Medieval tread mills for example were very dangerous. Many of them broke under stress, with disastrous consequences for those around it.

An other point to consider is what that trebuchet is used for. It looks like a very early form of air defense, which is preposterous to say the least. You could hit the wall of a castle with it, and that required some training plus trial and error. Castles usually don't move a lot. Trying to hit something that moved was simply not possible.

Comment: Game of Thrones is made up?!